# How can I make my algorithm more efficient?

Tags: trees, binary-search

I came across an algorithmic problem. I do not know how to do it optimally.

The problem is as follows:

> 1. There is an increasing array $A$ of size $n_1$
> 2. There is an array $M$ of queries of size $n_2$
>
>    where $1 \le n_1, n_2 \le 10^7$
>
> For each query element $m \in M$, it is required to find the count of elements in array $A$ that are strictly less than the query element $m$.
> For example:
>
> > $A = [1,2,3,5]$
> > $M = [4,2]$
> > for $m = 4$ answer $3$
> > for $m = 2$ answer $1$

My idea works for a $O(nlogn)$. The algorithm is simple; for each request I do a binary search in array $A$. But can it be faster? Maybe B-tree?

Comment: Can you credit the original source where you encountered this task?

Comment: @D.W. Сlosed group on codeforce from the university

Comment: Your hypothesis states that $A$ and $M$ are the same size $n$, but that is not the case in your example. Which is it? Also, are there hypotheses about the values in $A$? (if they are positives integers, there is an algorithm in $O(n+\max(A))$.)

Comment: @Nathaniel Sizes may be different, but within certain limits, I wrote inattentively, sorry. All values in both arrays are within $[1, 10^7]$ and are integers

Comment: @Nathaniel There is also an idea to try to somehow minimize the number of read cache lines per request

Comment: What if $M$ was notably smaller than $A$, say $9 \lvert M \rvert< \log\lvert A \rvert$?

Comment: Is there any reason why you think you might be able to improve on O(n_2 log (n_1))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If values in both arrays are positive integers, there is an algorithm in $O(n_1 + n_2 + \max(A))$. This algorithm is interesting if those three values are of the same order of magnitude.

The steps are as follow:

- check last element of $A$ to know $\max(A)$;
- create an array $B$ of size $\max(A)$;
- browse $A$ and modify $B$ so that $B[i]$ represents the smallest index $j$ such that $A[j] \geq i$ (that means the number of elements of $A$ that are $<i$);
- browse $M$; for $m \in M$, if $m > \max(A)$, return $n_1$, else return $B[m]$.

Comment: Wow, great solution, thanks a lot!